# I got a Type Error while training the dataset in YOLOv7, how to fix this?

Tags: python, deep-learning, yolov7

when I try to run train.py code, I get the error "TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc greater". I would be very grateful if you could help me figure out how to fix this.

The details of the error are as shown below.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\yolov7-gpu\train.py", line 616, in

```
train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
```

File "D:\yolov7-gpu\train.py", line 268, in train

```
tb_writer.add_histogram('classes', c, 0)
```

File "C:\Users\yildi\anaconda3\envs\yolov7-gpu-env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 485, in add_histogram

```
histogram(tag, values, bins, max_bins=max_bins), global_step, walltime
```

File "C:\Users\yildi\anaconda3\envs\yolov7-gpu-env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\summary.py", line 358, in histogram

```
hist = make_histogram(values.astype(float), bins, max_bins)
```

File "C:\Users\yildi\anaconda3\envs\yolov7-gpu-env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\summary.py", line 386, in make_histogram

```
cum_counts = np.cumsum(np.greater(counts, 0, dtype=np.int32))
```

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc greater

I have tried to train the dataset in cmd using;

python train.py --workers 0 --weights yolov7_training.pt --data data\plane.yaml --batch-size 4 --device 0 --img 640 640 --name yolov7-plane --hyp data\hyp.scratch.custom.yaml --epochs 200 --cfg cfg\training\yolov7-plane.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to check the version of pycocotools, numpy and tensorboard.   These ones work for me:

```
numpy==1.20.1 
pycocotools==2.0.2 
tensorboard==2.6.0
```